# Google Polymer: Toast prevents modals from exiting

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

just wondering if anybody else ran into the following problem, Basically, whenever you activate a paper-toast with a modal open, and you try exiting the modal by clicking outside of it, (the default paper-dialog functionality), the modal can't exit without the toast disappearing first. Is there a way to fix this or a workaround? Is this the expected behavior in Polymer?

Thanks!

Note: it might be worth pointing out that the toast has a fixed position at the bottom of the screen

Comment: can you add a working code snippet for same

Comment: So both elements inherit the behavior iron-overlay-behavior.  That means when show, it tries to put the element at highest z level and an invisible div that fills the viewport.  If you are showing 2 overlays, one is winning so what I would suggest is add an on-tap handler and close any dialog/toast.